finding velocity field in stationary from from earth velocity field
The earth rotates around the poles with an angular velocity $\omega$. This means that we are living in a moving and rotating frame.
If we know the velocity field of water $\textbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ at an instance of time in a very big sink at an latitute $\phi$ on the earth, how can we find  the velocity field in a stationary frame? The plane of the think is perpendicular to the radius of the earth.
Although this is a very interesting problem, I could not find any solution to this on the internet. Could someone help me solve this?


Do you not just add the velocity of the water to the rotational velocity of the Earth at that point?

I think this could lead to a coriolis effect which is different from just adding up velocities. @whpowell96 see this cool video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L5UD240mCQ

Coriolis effect is a virtual force, not a velocity. You just add the velocities to get the field at a single time instance

I do not understand what you mean by adding up the velocities. It is not a single velocity, it is a velocity feild @whpowell96

Maybe clarify your question a bit because it seems to me that @whpowell96 is correct. If you are trying to find a DE describing how the velocity of the water changes in the stationary frame (assuming no other forces but the ones keeping the water on the Earth), that is another story. But at any fixed time, the velocity of the water is just a relative velocity, and you just add that up with the velocity of that point on the Earth.

what if I want to find the velocity field instead of the velocity? there are some other forces in the fluid that lead to fluid motion, and i know the total flow because of this forces on this rotating frame. @RollenS.D'Souza
